# Return function from nested function in Python

Tags: python, return, nested-function

```
def method(x, y, z):
   def nested_method(a, b, c):
      if a + b + c < 7:
         for i in range(0, 7):
            if i == a + b +c
               return i
   nested_method(3, 4, 0)
   nested_method(3, 0, 1)
   nested_method(1, 2, 0)
```

returns in method:
None,
4,
3

If nested method returns something i want the method to return it.
When i only need one answer i firtsly check the more prioritiesed.

first priority: 3, 4 and 0

second priority: 3, 0 and 1

...

so it would return 4

Comment: Do you mean if `nested_method` returns `True`? Functions without a return statement return `None`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you would need to this? I would like to help, I just can't imagine a situation this would be best practice.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin i want the method to return a soon as one of the called nested_methods returns anything, because i call the nested_methods with higher priorities earlier then the one with lower

Comment: i need this for my tictactoe bot who firstly checks if he can win, then if the player can win, then if he could drop next to where he already dropped

Comment: if you want to return something from `method` you need to have a `return` statement in `method`...

Comment: `nested_method` returns `None` if it reaches the end of the loop without returning, so you can do something like `val = nested_method(3, 4, 0)` `if val is not None: return val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would return the first comparison that returns `True`

```
def method(a, b, c):
   def nested_method(d, e):
      if d == e:
         return True
   if nested_method(a, b):
      return nested_method(a, b)
   if nested_method(a, c):
      return nested_method(a, c)
   if nested_method(b, c):
      return nested_method(b, c)
```

You may want to add a printing statement to know which one is the one working...

This one would work in case that the three values are the same:

```
def method2(a, b, c):
   def nested_method(d, e):
      if d == e:
         return True
   
   comparisons = {'ab': nested_method(a, b), 'ac': nested_method(a, c), 'bc': nested_method(b, c)}

   return [comparisons[comp] for comp in comparisons if comparisons[comp] == True]
```

Comment: You might better use the `:=` operator to avoid repeatedly invoking `nested_method`. But `nested_method` can only return `True` or `None`.

Comment: is it possible so that the nested method returns method with its value without checking in outer scope

Comment: Not sure if I understand: Do you want the nested function to return the function that defines it?

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly yes

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly i think we missunderstand each other. i want that nested function returns 'return value' or something like that, so that if it returns the method function returns value

Comment: Please, edit your original question and add an example of what you expect. For example: what would you like to be the output if you call method(1,2,2)?

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly i did edit it

Comment: I think the first example in my answer should do that. It checks the results of nested_method in the order of "priorities" and returns the first one which returns something. Did you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you're looking for is:

```
def method(a, b, c):
   def nested_method(d, e):
      if d == e:
         return True
   if nested_method(a, b) is not None: return True
   if nested_method(a, c) is not None: return True
   if nested_method(b, c) is not None: return True
```

If you wish to know which pair match:

```
def method(a, b, c):
   def nested_method(d, e):
      if d == e:
         return True
   if nested_method(a, b) is not None: return ('a', 'b')
   if nested_method(a, c) is not None: return ('a', 'c')
   if nested_method(b, c) is not None: return ('b', 'c')
```

Given the effect `return` has upon control flow, this works, but you could also write the following, using a conditional expression rather than statement.

```
def method(a, b, c):
   def nested_method(d, e):
      if d == e:
         return True
   return ('a', 'b') if nested_method(a, b) else ('a', 'c') if nested_method(a, c) else ('b', 'c') if nested_method(b, c) else None
```

Comment: i mean is there a return return value or something like that, so that the nested function returns that the method needs to return the returned value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're looking for something like this:

```
def method(a, b, c):
    def nested_method(d, e):
        if d == e:
            return True

    for args in ((a, b), (b, c), (b, c)):
        if res := nested_method(*args) is not None: 
            return res # or return args
```

Comment: not exactly. in my code the nested_method is called much more often and returns an integer, so it would not work for me like that

Comment: He copy-pasted your code. It returns a boolean, not an integer. Maybe we're all trying to solve a problem different than the one you actually have.

Comment: @Ignatius Reilly the code written above is an example. it returns a boolean. but my actual code returns an integer

Comment: Basically I'm saying to make a list of the arguments you want to use, iterate over that list to call the nested method and for each iteration check if the nested method returned something other than None. If it does, then return that value.