# Avoiding repetition in a multi-tiered comparison function

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison, dry

I have a comparison function which looks something like this:

```
def compare(x, y):
  current = 0

  tmp = complicated_function(x, y)
  if tmp > 0:
    if current < 0:
      return 0 # incomparable
    current = -1
  elif tmp < 0:
    if current > 0:
      return 0 # incomparable
    current = 1

  tmp = complicated_function_2(x, y)
  if tmp > 0:
    if current < 0:
      return 0 # incomparable
    current = -1
  elif tmp < 0:
    if current > 0:
      return 0 # incomparable
    current = 1

  # ...

  return current
```

Basically, it does a lot of comparisons. If they are all compatible (a mix of 0s and 1s, a mix of 0s and -1s, or all 0s) then the result is returned; otherwise end early with a value of 0.

What's the most Pythonic method for implementing this? I'd love to do

```
def compare(x, y):
  current = 0
  def inner_compare(z):
    if z > 0:
      if current == -1:
        return 0 # <------- fails here
      current = 1
    if z < 0:
      if current == 1:
        return 0 # <------- fails here
      current = -1
  inner_compare(complicated_function(x, y))
  inner_compare(complicated_function_2(x, y))
  # ...
```

but of course that won't work since the inner function can't return the value to the outer function. I could use exceptions or flags but that just looks terrible. Since the structure is the same in each case I'd like to avoid repeating myself each time, any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535351/return-function-from-nested-function-in-python

Comment: You could define `inner_compare(z)` at the beggining and return the value you need. And inside `compare()` just call that function when you need: `compared_data=inner_compare(z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does one of these help? If not I may have misunderstood the question.
I'm assuming (0,0) returns a 1 (since 0 is the ends_early signal)

```
def compare1(x, y):
    if x >= 0 and y >= 0:
        return 1
    if x < 0 and y < 0:
        return -1
    return 0

#if (0,0) return something different then you can use this function
#just fill #in the last part under if x==0
def compare2(x, y):
    if x > 0:
        return 0 if y < 0 else 1
    if x < 0:
        return 0 if y > 0 else -1
    if x == 0:
        return "something" if y == 0 else "something_else"
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you loop through your complicated functions? That seems like a straightforward way to avoid repeating yourself.

```py
complicated_functions = [
    complicated_function,
    complicated_function_2,
    # ...
]

def compare(x, y):
    current = 0
    for cf in complicated_functions:
        tmp = cf(x, y)
        if tmp > 0:
            if current < 0:
                return 0 # incomparable
            current = -1
        elif tmp < 0:
            if current > 0:
                return 0 # incomparable
            current = 1
    
    # ...
    
    return current
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the functions and you can loop over the redundant conditionals that only differ in the sign (`+`, `-`) of some of the operands. YOu can also use an inner function:

```
funcs = [comp_func, comp_func_2, ...]

def compare(x, y):
    def inner_compare(z):
        for sign in (1, -1):
            if sign * z > 0:
                if sign * current < 0:
                    return 0 # incomparable
                return -1 * sign

    current = 0
    for cf in funcs:
        if (current := inner_compare(cf(x, y))) == 0:
            break
    return current
```

Answer (score 0):

first try

```
def compare(x,y):
    import math
    
    current = complicated_function(x, y)
    
    tmp = complicated_function_2(x, y)
    if current * tmp > 0:
        return 0
    if tmp:
        current = tmp

    # ...

    return math.copysign(1, -current) if current else 0
```

second try

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

def compare(x,y):
    
    signs = np.sign([
        complicated_function(x, y),
        complicated_function_2(x, y),
        ...
        complicated_function_n(x, y)
        ])

    tmp = [x for x in signs if x != 0]
    if len(tmp) == 0:
        return 0
    pair_sums = list(map(sum, it.pairwise(tmp)))
    remains = [x for x in pair_sums if x != 0]
    return len(remains) == 0
```

`signs`: the sign of each function value.

`tmp`: filters the '0' values from `signs`.
if `tmp` is empty, return 0.

At this point `tmp` should contain an alternating pattern of 1's and -1's. If it doesn't, return 0.

`pair_sums`: should be a list of 0's.

`remains`: if non-empty then `tmp` contained adjacent elements with the same value, so return 0; otherwise return 1.

Comment: A minor detail to watch for—if `current` and `tmp` are of types that can overflow (e.g., numpy's `np.int8` type), `current * tmp > 0` isn't a reliable way to check if `current` and `tmp` have the same sign.

Comment: @fakedad Definitely something to watch for in general, but the multiplication won’t overflow in my case.

Comment: So your suggestion is to repeat the (simplified) code block each time? Yes, the first time I can just assign.

Comment: Yes, repeat the code block beginning with the `tmp` assignment. From your code I assumed you were going for lazy evaluation of the functions. If not then the second try should resolve @fakedad caveat.